# Ayuda Objetos Json recorrer y mostrarlo DOM Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, eventos, dom

necesito ayuda, no se como sacar esto
 Si se hace clic en una comarca debe aparecer a su lado la capital en color rojo y abajo en diferentes sub-líneas todas las poblaciones ordenadas alfabéticamente (que obtendrá SIEMPRE del JSON)

• Comarcas barceloneses - Provincia de Barcelona
  ◦ Barcelones Barcelona
▪ Badalona
▪ Barcelona
▪ Hospitalet
  ▪ ...

El código que tengo me imprime las Comarques una debajo de otra, por ejemplo al hacer click en Comarques Barceloneses se muestra

- Barcelones
- Baix Llobregat
- Valles Occidental
- ..

Ahora lo que necesito es que al hacer click por ejemplo en Barcelones se muestre su Capital y sus ciudades.Solo mostrar cuando se hace click encima del que queremos ver.
No consigo entrar para sacar la capital y ciudades, no se como hacerlo.

```js
var comarques = {
 'Comarques barceloneses' : {
  'Barcelonés' : {
   'capital' : 'Barcelona',
   'ciutats' : 'Badalona,Barcelona,Hospitalet de Llobregat,San Adriàn de Besós,Santa Coloma de Gramanet'
  },
  'Baix Llobregat': {
   'capital' : 'San Feliú de Llobregat',
   'ciutats' : 'Abrera,Begas,Casteldefels,Castellví de Rosanes,Cervelló,Collbató,Corbera de Llobregat,Cornellà de Llobregat,Esparraguera,Esplugas de Llobregat,Gavà,Martorell,Molins de Rey,Olesa de Montserrat,Pallejà,La Palma de Cervelló,El Papiol,El Prat de Llobregat,San Andrés de la Barca,San Baudilio de Llobregat,San Clemente de Llobregat,San Esteban de Sasroviras,San Feliú de Llobregat,San Juan Despí,San Justo Desvern,San Vicente dels Horts,Santa Coloma de Cervelló,Torrellas de Llobregat,Vallirana,Viladecans'
  },
  'Vallès Occidental' : {
   'capital' : 'Barcelona',
   'ciutats' : 'Badia del Vallès,Barberà del Vallés,Castellar del Vallés,Castellbisbal,Sardañola del Vallés,Gallifa,Matadepera,Moncada,Reixach,Palau-solità,Plegamans,Polinyà,Rellinars,Ripollet,Rubí,Sabadell,San Cugat del Vallés,San Lorenzo Savall,San Quirico de Tarrasa,Santa Perpetua de Moguda,Senmanat,Tarrasa,Ullastrell,Vacarisas,Viladecavalls'
  },
  'Vallès Oriental' : {
   'capital' : 'Granollers',
   'ciutats' : 'Aiguafreda,La Ametlla,Bigas,Caldas de Montbui,Campins,Canovellas,Cànoves,Cardedeu,Castellcir,Castelltersol,Figaró-Montmany,Fogàs de Monclús,Las Franquesas del Vallés,La Garriga,Granera,Granollers,Gualba,La Llagosta,Llinàs del Vallés,Llissà de Munt,Llissà de Vall,Martorellas,Mollet del Vallès,Montmeló,Montornés del Vallés,Montseny,Parets,La Roca del Vallés,San Antonio Vilamajor,San Celoni,San Esteban de Palautordera,San Felíu de Codinas,San Fausto de Campcentellas,San Pedro de Vilamajor,San Quirico Safaja,Santa Eulalia de Ronsana,Santa María de Martorellas de Arriba,Santa María de Palautordera,Tagamanent,Vallgorguina,Vallromanes,Villalba Saserra,Vilanova del Vallés'
  },      
  'El Maresme' : {
   'capital' : 'Mataró',
   'ciutats' : 'Alella,Arenys de Mar,Arenys de Munt,Argentona,Cabrera de Mar,Cabrils,Caldetas,Calella,Canet de Mar,Dosrius,Malgrat de Mar,El Masnou,Mataró,Montgat,Orrius,Palafolls,Pineda de Mar,Premià de Dalt,Premià de Mar,San Andrés de Llavaneras,San Cipriano de Vallalta,San Acisclo de Vallalta,San Pol de Mar,San Vicente de Montalt,Santa Susana,Teyà,Tiana,Tordera,Vilasar de Dalt,Vilasar de Mar'
  },
  'Garraf' : {
   'capital' : 'Villanueva,Geltrú',
   'ciutats' : 'Canyellas,Cubellas,Olivella,San Pedro de Ribas,Sitges,Villanueva,Geltrú'
  }, 
  'Alt Penedès' : {
   'capital' : 'Villafranca del Panadés',
   'ciutats' : 'Avinyonet del Penedés,Las Cabanyas,Castellet,Gornal,Castellví de la Marca,Fontrubí,Gelida,La Granada,Mediona,Olèrdola,Olesa de Bonesvalls,Pachs del Panadés,Pla del Panadés,Pontons,Puigdalba,San Cugat Sasgarrigas,San Lorenzo de Hortóns,San Martín Sarroca,San Pedro de Riudevitlles,San Quintín de Mediona,San Sadurní de Noya,Santa Fe del Panadés,Santa Margarita,Monjós,Subirats,Torrelavit,Torrellas de Foix,Villafranca del Panadés,Viloví'
  },
  'Anoia' : {
   'capital' : 'Igualada',
   'ciutats' : 'Argensola,Bellprat,Bruch,Cabrera de Igualada,Calaf,Calonge de Segarra,Capellades,Carme,Castellfollit de Riubregós,Castellolí,Copóns,Els Hostalets de Pierola,Igualada,Jorba,La Llacuna,Masquefa,Montmaneu,Ódena,Orpí,Piera,La Pobla de Claramunt,Prats del Rey,Pujalt,Rubió,San Martín de Tous,San Martín Sasgayolas,Salavinera,Santa Margarita de Montbuy,Santa María de Miralles,Torre de Claramunt,Vallbona,Veciana,Vilanova del Camí'
  },
  'Bages' : {
   'capital' : 'Manresa',
   'ciutats' : 'Aguilar de Segarra,Artés,Avinyó,Balsareny,Calders,Callús,Cardona,Castellbell,Vilar,Castellfullit del Boix,Castellgalí,Castellnou de Bages,Estany,Fonollosa,Gayà,Manresa,Marganell,Moyà,Monistrol de Calders,Monistrol de Montserrat,Mura,Navarclés,Navàs,El Pont de Vilomara,Rocafort,Rajadell,Sallent de Llobregat,San Felíu Saserra,San Fructuoso de Bages,San Juan de Torruella,San Mateo de Bages,Guardiola,San Vicente de Castellet,Santa Maria d\'Oló,Sampedor,Súria,Talamanca'
  }
 },
 'Comarques gerundenses' : {
  'Gironès' : {
   'capital' : 'Gerona',
   'ciutats' : 'Aiguaviva,Bescanó,Bordils,Camplloch,Canet de Adri,Cassà de la Selva,Celrà,Cervià de Ter,Flassà,Fornells de la Selva,Gerona,Juyà,Llagostera,Llambillas,Madremaña,Quart,Salt,San Andrés Salou,San Gregorio,San Juan de Mollet,San Jordi Desvalls,San Juliàn de Ramis,San Martín de Liémana,San Martivell,Sarrià de Ter,Vilablareix,Viladasens'
  },
  'Pla de l\'Estany' : {
   'capital' : 'Bañolas',
   'ciutats' : 'Agullana,Albañà,La Armentera,Aviñonet de Puig Ventós,Bàscara,Viure,Buadella,Borrassà,Cabanellas,Cabanas,Cadaqués,Cantallops,Capmany,Castellón de Ampurias,Cistella,Ciurana,Colera,Darnius,La Escala,Espolla,Alfar,Figueras,Fortià,Garrigàs,Garriguella,La Junquera,Lladó,Llansà,Llers,Masarach,Massanet de Cabrenys,Mollet de Peralada,Navata,Ordis,Palau de Santa Eulalia,Palau Sabardera,Pau,Pedret,Marsà,Perelada,Pont de Molins,Pontós,Puerto de la Selva,Portbou,Rabós,Riumors,Rosas,San Clemente Sasebas,San Lorenzo de la Muga,San Miguel de Fluvià,San Mori,San Pedro Pescador,Santa Leocadia de Algama; Saus,Camallera,Llampaies; La Selva de Mar,Terradas,Torroella de Fluvià,La Bajol,Ventalló,Vilabertran,Viladamat,Vilafant,Vilajuïga,Vilamacolum,Vilamalla,Vilamaniscle,Vilanant,Vilasacra,Vilahur'
  },
  'Alt Empordà' : {
   'capital' : 'Figueras',
   'ciutats' : 'Agullana,Albañà,La Armentera,Aviñonet de Puig Ventós,Bàscara,Viure,Buadella,Borrassà,Cabanellas,Cabanas,Cadaqués,Cantallops,Capmany,Castellón de Ampurias,Cistella,Ciurana,Colera,Darnius,La Escala,Espolla,Alfar,Figueras,Fortià,Garrigàs,Garriguella,La Junquera,Lladó,Llansà,Llers,Masarach,Massanet de Cabrenys,Mollet de Peralada,Navata,Ordis,Palau de Santa Eulalia,Palau Sabardera,Pau,Pedret,Marsà,Perelada,Pont de Molins,Pontós,Puerto de la Selva,Portbou,Rabós,Riumors,Rosas,San Clemente Sasebas,San Lorenzo de la Muga,San Miguel de Fluvià,San Mori,San Pedro Pescador,Santa Leocadia de Algama; Saus,Camallera,Llampaies; La Selva de Mar,Terradas,Torroella de Fluvià,La Bajol,Ventalló,Vilabertran,Viladamat,Vilafant,Vilajuïga,Vilamacolum,Vilamalla,Vilamaniscle,Vilanant,Vilasacra,Vilahur'
  },
  'Baix Empordà' : {
   'capital' : 'La Bisbal del Ampurdàn',
   'ciutats' : 'Albons,Bagur,Bellcaire,La Bisbal del Ampurdàn,Calonge,Castillo de Aro,Colomés,Corsà; Cruilles,Monells,San Sadurní; Foixà,Fontanillas,Forallac,Garrigolas,Gualta,Jafre,Montràs,Palafrugell,Palamós,Palau-sator,Pals,Parlabà,La Pera,Regencós,Rupià,San Feliu de Guíxols,Santa Cristina de Aro,Serra de Daró,La Tallada,Torrent,Torroella de Montgrí,Ullà,Ullastret,Ultramort,Vall-llobrega,Verges,Vilopriu'
  },
  'La Garrotxa' : {
   'capital' : 'Olot',
   'ciutats' : 'Argelaguer,Besalú,Beuda,Castellfullit de la Roca,Mayà de Moncal,Mieras,Montagut,Oix,Olot,Las Planas,Las Presas,Riudaura,Sales de Llierca,Sant Aniol de Finestràs,San Feliu de Pallarols,San Ferreol,San Jaime de Llierca,San Juan les Fonts,Santa Pau,Tortellà,Vall de Vianya,Vall de Bas'
  },
  'Ripollès' : {
   'capital' : 'Ripoll',
   'ciutats' : 'Campdevànol,Campellas,Camprodón,Gombreny,Llanàs,Las Llosas,Molló,Ogassa,Pardinas,Planolas,Queralbs,Ribas de Freser,Ripoll,San Cristóbal de Tosas,San Juan de las Abadesas,San Pablo de Seguríes,Setcasas,Vallfogona,Vilallonga de Ter'
  },
 },
 'Comarques leridanas' : {
  'Segrià' : {
   'capital' : 'Lérida',
   'ciutats' : 'Aitona,Alamús,Albatarrech,Alcanó,Alcarràs,Alcoletge,Alfarràs,Alfés,Alguaire,Almacellas,Almatret,Almenar,Alpicat,Artesa de Lérida,Aspa,Benavent de Lérida,Corbins,Gimenells,el Pla de la Font,La Granja de Escarpe,Llardecans,Lérida,Mayals,Masalcorreig,Montoliu,Portella,Puigvert de Lérida,Rosselló,Sarroca,Serós,Soses,Sudanell,Suñer,Torrebeses,Torrefarrera,Torres de Segre,Torre-serona,Vilanova de la Barca,Vilanova de Segrià'
  },
  'Les Garrigues' : {
   'capital' : 'Borjas Blancas',
   'ciutats' : 'Albagés,Albí,Arbeca,Bellaguarda,Borjas Blancas,Bovera,Castelldans,Cervià,El Cogul,Espluga Calva,La Floresta,Fulleda,La Granadella,Grañena de las Garrigas,Juncosa,Juneda,Omellóns,Pobla de Ciérvoles,Puig Gros,Soleràs,Tarrés,Torms,Vilosell,Vinaixa'
  },
  'Pla d\'Urgell' : {
   'capital' : 'Mollerusa',
   'ciutats' : 'Barbens,Bell Lloch,Bellvís,Castellnou de Seana,Fondarella,Golmés,Ibars de Urgel,Liñola,Miralcamp,Mollerusa,Palau de Anglesola,Poal,Sidamunt,Torregrosa,Vilanova de Bellpuig,Vilasana'
  },
  'Baix Urgell' : {
   'capital' : 'Tàrrega',
   'ciutats' : 'Agramunt,Anglesola,Belianes,Bellpuig,Castellserà,Ciutadilla,La Fuliola,Guimerà,Maldà,Nalech,Omélls de Nagaya,Ossó de Sió,Preixana,Puigvert de Agramunt,Sant Martí de Riucorb,Tàrrega,Tornabous,Vallbona de las Monjas,Verdú,Vilagrasa'
  },
  'Segarra' : {
   'capital' : 'Cervera',
   'ciutats' : 'Biosca,Cervera,Estaràs,Grañanella,Grañena,Guisona,Iborra,Masoteras,Montolíu de Cervera,Montornés de Segarra,Olujas,Els Plans de Sió,Ribera del Ondara,Sanahuja,San Guim de Freixanet,Sant Guim de la Plana,San Ramón,Talavera,Tarroja de Segarra,Torà,Torreflor'
  },
  'Noguera' : {
   'capital' : 'Balaguer',
   'ciutats' : 'Ager,Albesa,Algerri,Alós de Balaguer,Artesa de Segre,Avellanes Santa Liña,Balaguer,La Baronia de Rialb,Bellcaire d\'Urgell,Bellmunt de Urgel,Cabanabona,Camarasa,Castellón de Farfaña,Cubells,Foradada,Ibars de Noguera,Menarguéns,Montgai,Oliola,Os de Balaguer,Penelles,Ponts,Preixens,La Sentiu de Sió,Térmens,Tiurana,Torrelameu,Vallfogona de Balaguer,Vilanova de la Aguda,Vilanova de Meyà'
  },
  'Solsonès' : {
   'capital' : 'Solsona',
   'ciutats' : 'Castellar de la Ribera,Clariana de Cardener,La Coma,la Pedra,Guixers,Lladurs,Llobera,La Molsosa,Navés,Odén,Olius,Pinell,Pinós,Riner,San Lorenzo de Morunys,Solsona'
  },
  'Alt Urgell' : {
   'capital' : 'Seo de Urgel',
   'ciutats' : 'Alàs Serch,Arseguell,Basella,Cabó,Cava,Coll de Nargó,Estamariu,Fígols,Aliñà,Josà Tuixent,Montferrer Castellbó,Oliana,Orgaña,Peramola,El Pont de Bar,Ribera de Urgellet,Seo de Urgel,Valls d\'Aguilar,Valles del Valira,La Vansa,Fórnols'
  },
  'Pallars Sobirà' : {
   'capital' : 'Sort',
   'ciutats' : 'Alíns,Alto Aneu,Baix Pallars,Espot,Esterri de Aneu,Esterri de Cardós,Farrera,La Guingueta,Lladorre,Llavorsí,Rialp,Soriguera,Sort,Tirvia,Vall de Cardós'
  },
  'Pallars Jussà' : {
   'capital' : 'Tremp',
   'ciutats' : 'Abella de la Conca,Castell de Mur,Conca de Dalt,Gavet de la Conca,Isona,Conca Dellà,Llimiana,Puebla de Segur,Salàs de Pallars,San Esteban de la Sarga,Sarroca de Bellera,Senterada,Talarn,Torre de Capdella,Tremp'
  },
  'Alta Ribagorça' : {
   'capital' : 'El Pont de Suert',
   'ciutats' : 'El Pont de Suert,Valle de Bohí,Vilaller'
  },
  'Vall d\'Aran' : {
   'capital' : 'Viella',
   'ciutats' : 'Alto Aràn,Arrés,Bausen,Las Bordas,Bosost,Canejan,Les,Viella Mitg Aràn,Vilamós'
  }
 },
 'Comarques mixtas' : {
  'Osona' : {
   'capital' : 'Vich',
   'ciutats' : 'Alpens [B],Balenyà [B],Brull [B],Calldetenes [B],Centellas [B],Collsuspina [B],Espinelvas [G],Folgarolas [B],Gurb [B],Llusà [B],Malla [B],Manlleu [B],Masías de Roda [B],Las Masías de Voltregà [B],Montesquiu [B],Montanyola [B],Olost [B],Orís [B],Oristà [B],Perafita [B],Prats de Llusanés [B],Roda de Ter [B],Rupit,Pruït [B],San Agustín de Llusanés [B],San Bartolomé del Grau [B],San Baudilio de Llusanés [B],San Hipólito de Voltregà [B],San Juliàn de Vilatorta [B],San Martín del Bas [B],San Martín de Centellas [B],San Pedro de Torelló [B],San Quirico de Besora [B],San Saturnino de Osormot [B],San Vicente de Torelló [B],Santa Cecilia de Voltregà [B],Santa Eugenia de Berga [B],Santa Eulalia de Riuprimer [B],Santa María de Besora [B],Santa Maria de Corcó [B],Seva [B],Sobremunt [B],Sora [B],Taradell [B],Tabérnolas [B],Tavertet [B],Tona [B],Torelló [B],Vich [B],Vidrà [G],Viladrau [G],Vilanova de Sau [B]'
  },
  'La Selva' : {
   'capital' : 'Santa Coloma de Farnés',
   'ciutats' : 'Amer [G],Anglés [G],Arbucias [G],Blanes [G],Breda [G],Bruñola [G],Caldas de Malavella [G],Fogàs de Tordera [B],Hostalrich [G],Lloret de Mar [G],Massanas [G],Massanet de la Selva [G],Osor [G],Riells [G],Riudarenas [G],Riudellots de la Selva [G],San Felíu de Buxalleu [G],San Hilario Sacalm [G],Sant Julià del Llor,Bonmatí [G],Santa Coloma de Farnés [G],La Sellera de Ter [G],Sils [G],Susqueda [G],Tossa de Mar [G],Vidreras [G],Viloví de Oñar [G]'
  },
  'Baixa Cerdanya' : {
   'capital' : 'Puigcerdà',
   'ciutats' : 'Alp [G],Bellver de Cerdaña [L],Bolvir [G],Das [G],Fontanals de Cerdaña [G],Ger [G],Guils de Cerdaña [G],Isóbol [G],Lles [L],Llivia [G],Maranges [G],Montellà,Martinet [L],Prats,Sampsor [L],Prullans [L],Puigcerdà [G],Riu de Cerdaña [L],Urús [G]'
  },
  'Berguedà' : {
   'capital' : 'Berga',
   'ciutats' : 'Avià [B],Bagà [B],Berga [B],Borredà [B],Capolat [B],Caserras [B],Castell del Areny [B],Castellar de Nuch [B],Castellar del Riu [B],Espunyola [B],Fígols [B],Gironella [B],Gisclareny [B],Gósol [L],Guardiola de Berga [B],Montclar de Urgel [B],Montmajor [B],La Nou [B],Olvàn [B],La Pobla de Lillet [B],Puigreig [B],La Quart [B],Sagàs [B],Saldes [B],San Jaime de Frontanya [B],San Juliàn de Cerdañola [B],Santa María de Marlés [B],Serchs [B],Vallcebre [B],Vilada [B],Viver,Serrateix [B]'
  }
 },
 'Comarques tarraconenses' : {
  'Tarragonès' : {
   'capital' : 'Tarragona',
   'ciutats' : 'Altafulla,La Canonja,El Catllar,Constantí,Creixell,Morell,La Nou de Gaya,Pallaresos,Perafort,Pobla de Mafumet,Puebla de Montornés,Renau,La Riera,Roda de Bará,Salomó,Salou,La Secuita,Tarragona,Torredembarra,Vespella,Vilallonga del Camp,Vilaseca'
  },
  'Alt Camp' : {
   'capital' : 'Valls',
   'ciutats' : 'Aiguamurcia,Alcover,Alió,Bràfim,Cabra del Campo,Figuerola del Camp,Garidells,La Masó,Milá,Montferri,Montreal,Nulles,Pla de Santa María,Puente de Armentera,Puigpelat,Querol,La Riba,Rodoñá,Rourell,Vallmoll,Valls,Vilabella,Vila-rodona'
  },
  'Baix Camp' : {
   'capital' : 'Reus',
   'ciutats' : 'Albiol,Aleixar,Alforja,Almoster,Arbolí,Argentera,Borjas del Campo,Botarell,Cambrils,Capafons,Castellvell,Colldejou,Dosaiguas,La Febró,Maspujols,Montbrió de Tarragona,Montroig,Prades,Pratdip,Reus,Riudecañas,Riudecols,Riudoms,La Selva del Campo,Vandellós,Hospitalet del Infante,Vilanova d\'Escornalbou,Vilaplana,Viñols,Archs'
  },
  'Baix Penedès' : {
   'capital' : 'Vendrell',
   'ciutats' : 'Albiñana,Arbós,Bañeras (Tarragona),Bellvey,La Bisbal del Panadés,Bonastre,Calafell,Cunit,Lloréns,Maslloréns,El Montmell,San Jaime dels Domenys,Santa Oliva,Vendrell'
  },
  'Conca de Barberà' : {
   'capital' : 'Montblanch',
   'ciutats' : 'Barbará,Blancafort,Conesa,Espluga de Francolí,Forés,Llorach,Montblanch,Pasanant,Las Pilas,Pira (Tarragona),Pontils,Rocafort de Queralt,Santa Coloma de Queralt,Sarral,Savallá del Condado,Senan,Solivella,Vallclara,Vallfogona de Riucorb,Vilanova de Prades,Vilavert,Vimbodí,Poblet'
  },
  'El Priorat' : {
   'capital' : 'Falset',
   'ciutats' : 'Bellmunt del Priorato,La Bisbal de Falset,Cabacés,Capsanes,Cornudella,Falset,La Figuera,Gratallops,Guiamets,Lloá,Margalef de Montsant,Marsá,El Masroig,El Molar,La Morera de Montsant,Poboleda,Porrera,Pradell,Torre de Fontaubella,Torroja,Ulldemolins,Vilella Alta,Vilella Baja'
  },
  'Ribera d\'Ebre' : {
   'capital' : 'Mora de Ebro',
   'ciutats' : 'Ascó,Benisanet,Flix,Garcia,Ginestar,Miravet,Mora de Ebro,Mora la Nueva,La Palma de Ebro,Rasquera,Ribarroja de Ebro,Tivisa,Torre del Español,Vinebre'
  },
  'Terra Alta' : {
   'capital' : 'Gandesa',
   'ciutats' : 'Arnes,Batea,Bot,Caseres,Corbera de Ebro,La Fatarella,Gandesa,Horta de San Juan,Pinell de Bray,Puebla de Masaluca,Prat de Compte,Villalba de los Arcos'
  },
  'Baix Ebre' : {
   'capital' : 'Tortosa',
   'ciutats' : 'La Aldea,Aldover,Alfara (Tarragona),La Ametlla de Mar,La Ampolla,Benifallet,Camarles,i Cherta,Deltebre,Pauls,Perelló,Roquetas,Tivenys,Tortosa'
  },
  'Montsià' : {
   'capital' : 'Amposta',
   'ciutats' : 'Alcanar,Amposta,Cenia,Freginals,La Galera,Godall,Mas de Barberans,Masdenverge,San Carlos de la Rápita,San Jaime de Enveija,Santa Bárbara,Ulldecona'
  }   
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="Catalunya.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  
        
     
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            
            <p></p>
            
        </div>   
    </body>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function (){
             var cont=0;
             for(provincies in comarques){
                 var parrafo = document.createElement("p"); 
                 parrafo.setAttribute('id',cont);
                 var nprovincia= document.createTextNode(provincies);
                 $(parrafo).append(nprovincia);
                 $(parrafo).insertBefore("div");
                 cont++;
             }
             $("p").click(function (){
                 var cont=0;  
                 //alert(this.innerText);
                 for(comarca in comarques[this.innerText]){
                     var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
                     parrafo.setAttribute('id',cont);
                     var ncomarca = document.createTextNode(comarca);
                     $(this).append(parrafo);
                     $(parrafo).append(ncomarca);
                      cont++;
    
                 } 
             });
             
             $("p"(class="capital")).click(function (){
                 var cont=0;
                 for(capital in comarques[this.parentNode.firstChild]){
                     alert("HOLA");
                 }
                 
                 
                     
                 
                
               
             });
             /* ESTA MAL 
                 $("p"(class="capital").click(function (){
                 var cont=0;
                 for(capitall in comarques[this.parentNode.firstChild]){
                     alert("HOLA");
                 }
             

             for(capital in comarques[this.parentNode.childNodes[0]][.nodeValue][this.innerText]){
             this.innertext -> girones
             this.parentNode.childNodes[0]innerText  -> es tot
             
             //addeventLisenet a cada paragraf
             for(capital in comarques[this.parentNode.childNodes[0]][this.innerText].nodeValue){
                     alert(this.innerText);*/
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
         });
        
       
    </script>
   
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hice un ejemplo que funciona OK tomando lo tuyo como punto de partida. Entiendo que lo importante en este caso es el acceso a las ciudades y la capital.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="Catalunya.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>



    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

            <p></p>

        </div>   
    </body>
    <script>

            var comarques={
    'Comarques leridanas': {
        'Segrià': {
            "capital": "Lérida",
            "ciutats": "Aitona,Alamús,Albatarrech,Alcanó,Alcarràs,Alcoletge,Alfarràs,Alfés,Alguaire,Almacellas,Almatret,Almenar,Alpicat,Artesa de Lérida,Aspa,Benavent de Lérida,Corbins,Gimenells,el Pla de la Font,La Granja de Escarpe,Llardecans,Lérida,Mayals,Masalcorreig,Montoliu,Portella,Puigvert de Lérida,Rosselló,Sarroca,Serós,Soses,Sudanell,Suñer,Torrebeses,Torrefarrera,Torres de Segre,Torre-serona,Vilanova de la Barca,Vilanova de Segrià"
        },
        "Les Garrigues": {
            "capital": "Borjas Blancas",
            "ciutats": "Albagés,Albí,Arbeca,Bellaguarda,Borjas Blancas,Bovera,Castelldans,Cervià,El Cogul,Espluga Calva,La Floresta,Fulleda,La Granadella,Grañena de las Garrigas,Juncosa,Juneda,Omellóns,Pobla de Ciérvoles,Puig Gros,Soleràs,Tarrés,Torms,Vilosell,Vinaixa"
        }

    },
    "Comarques mixtas": {
        "Osona": {
            "capital": "Vich",
            "ciutats": "Alpens [B],Balenyà [B],Brull [B],Calldetenes [B],Centellas [B],Collsuspina [B],Espinelvas [G],Folgarolas [B],Gurb [B],Llusà [B],Malla [B],Manlleu [B],Masías de Roda [B],Las Masías de Voltregà [B],Montesquiu [B],Montanyola [B],Olost [B],Orís [B],Oristà [B],Perafita [B],Prats de Llusanés [B],Roda de Ter [B],Rupit,Pruït [B],San Agustín de Llusanés [B],San Bartolomé del Grau [B],San Baudilio de Llusanés [B],San Hipólito de Voltregà [B],San Juliàn de Vilatorta [B],San Martín del Bas [B],San Martín de Centellas [B],San Pedro de Torelló [B],San Quirico de Besora [B],San Saturnino de Osormot [B],San Vicente de Torelló [B],Santa Cecilia de Voltregà [B],Santa Eugenia de Berga [B],Santa Eulalia de Riuprimer [B],Santa María de Besora [B],Santa Maria de Corcó [B],Seva [B],Sobremunt [B],Sora [B],Taradell [B],Tabérnolas [B],Tavertet [B],Tona [B],Torelló [B],Vich [B],Vidrà [G],Viladrau [G],Vilanova de Sau [B]"
        },
        "La Selva": {
            "capital": "Santa Coloma de Farnés",
            "ciutats": "Amer [G],Anglés [G],Arbucias [G],Blanes [G],Breda [G],Bruñola [G],Caldas de Malavella [G],Fogàs de Tordera [B],Hostalrich [G],Lloret de Mar [G],Massanas [G],Massanet de la Selva [G],Osor [G],Riells [G],Riudarenas [G],Riudellots de la Selva [G],San Felíu de Buxalleu [G],San Hilario Sacalm [G],Sant Julià del Llor,Bonmatí [G],Santa Coloma de Farnés [G],La Sellera de Ter [G],Sils [G],Susqueda [G],Tossa de Mar [G],Vidreras [G],Viloví de Oñar [G]"
        }

    }
}       

         $(document).ready(function (){          
             var cont=0;
             for(provincies in comarques){
                 var parrafo = document.createElement("p"); 
                 parrafo.setAttribute('id',cont);
                 var nprovincia= document.createTextNode(provincies);
                 $(parrafo).append(nprovincia);
                 $(parrafo).insertBefore("div");
                 cont++;
             }
              $("p").click(function (){
                 var cont=0;  

                 var texto=this.innerText;              
                 for(comarca in comarques[this.innerText]){
                     var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
                     parrafo.setAttribute('id',cont);
                     var ncomarca = document.createTextNode(comarca);       
                     parrafo.addEventListener("click", function() {                                                            
                                                                    var capital=comarques[texto][this.innerText]["capital"];
                                                                    var ncapital=document.createTextNode(capital);
                                                                    var ciutats=comarques[texto][this.innerText]["ciutats"];
                                                                    var nciutats=document.createTextNode(ciutats);
                                                                    var parrafocapital = document.createElement("p");
                                                                    $(parrafocapital).append(ncapital)                                                                  
                                                                    var parrafociutats=document.createElement("p");
                                                                    $(parrafociutats).append(nciutats);
                                                                    $(this).append(parrafocapital);
                                                                    $(this).append(parrafociutats);                                                                 

                                                                    }, true);   
                     $(this).append(parrafo);
                     $(parrafo).append(ncomarca);

                      cont++;


                 } 
             });            




         });


    </script>



</html>
```

Saludos y espero sea de tu utilidad.